# Access FirebaseUser in all state flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I would like to know what is the best practice for accessing the logged in user in all the app. 
and don't do `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((result) {...});` in all init state.

I have two ideas, make a singleton which is initialized when I start my application.
And listen `onAuthStateChanged`.

```
class GlobalDataAppli {
  static final GlobalDataAppli _appData = new GlobalDataAppli._internal();

  FirebaseUser user;
  IdTokenResult userToken;
  List<Post> myListPost;

  factory GlobalDataAppli() {
    return _appData;
  }

  GlobalDataAppli._internal();
}
final globalData = GlobalDataAppli;
```

Or i have see Inherited Widgets. But this will only share my users for child widgets, not when changing views.

I would also like to share a list of posts across the app. Indeed, the same post can be visible in several pages, so I want to keep in memory all the posts currently displayed, so that each post widget will be based on the same variable. Thus, the modification of a post on a view is reflected on each view that displays this post. (Currently I have passed this list as a parameter for each view, and it works, but I know that is not the right way to do it).

Somebody know the best practice for that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common options are:

1. Use `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()`. While you explicitly say you don't want to do this, it is actually what I'd recommend as a first implementation as it is most likely to give you the up-to-date authentication state.
2. Listen for the [`onAuthStateChanged` stream](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/onAuthStateChanged.html), which ensures you'll also pick up things like when the user gets signed out (for example: if you disable their account in the Firebase console). This one is a bit more work than just getting `currentUser()` though.
3. Pass the current user value around in `SharedPreferences`. I like this approach less, as it requires me to write code for state management that Firebase already does.

If you're inclined to not use one of the first two approaches, you'll want to think carefully about why that is, and validate those assumptions. For example: both approaches work from the local authentication state after the first call, which means that performance will be as good as any alternative you implement yourself.

Comment: Okey, thank you Frank. I will get the currentUser() instance in each widget parent, and propagated to children using an inherited widget.